# google chrome shortcut does not bring up blank page when shortcut placed on taskbar

Tags: google-chrome, taskbar, shortcuts

I have a few google chrome shortcuts on my windows 7 desktop.
One of them opens my Hotmail in google chrome.
One of them opens my google calendar.
And of course there is the original google chrome shortcut that opens a blank page in google chrome.
I want to create a shortcut on my taskbar to open a blank page in google chrome.
So I make sure google chrome is not running and I click on the original google chrome shortcut that brings up a blank page.
I then pin that to the taskbar.
The problem is, whenever I click the pinned shortcut, google chrome opens my Hotmail, which is not what I want it to do.
I'm not sure why the OS is changing it when pinning.
How can I fix?

Comment: Are you sure the homepage for Chrome is not hotmail? What if you pinned the .exe shortcut instead?

Comment: Did you check "On Startup" is set to "Open the New Tab page" under chrome Menu > Settings ?.

Comment: There is no home page set in chrome.  If I right-click any chrome taskbar shortcut and click NEW WINDOW it opens to a blank page.  And if I use the original shortcut it opens to a blank page.  How would I pin the .exe - I can only pin something that is already running.  ON STARTUP is set to OPEN THE NEW TAB PAGE